# Formatting on form not enough room for labels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to mvc I am having some styling issues here with my form for some reason. I dont appear to have enough room for my text labels and its being squashed full screen.

I do not no if begin form would mess with the styling or not but having a real issue here.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Step1", "Forms", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
<h4>Health Check - Personal Details</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("First Name", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Middle Name", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtmiddleName" name="txtMiddleName" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Surname", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Saluation", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtSaluation" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Aliases", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtAliases" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Maritial Status", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Address 1", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtAddress1" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Address 2", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtAddress2" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("City", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            @Html.Label("Post Code", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("County", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtCounty" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Country", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Date Of Birth", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("datepicker"))


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Home Tel No", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Home Work No", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtmStatus" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Fax No", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtFaxNo" name="txtFaxNo" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                @Html.Label("Mobile No", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input id="txtMobile" name="txtMobile" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

[image]

Answer 1 works ok for full screen but when mobile it shows as this

[image: Mobile Render View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.Label("Surname", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
```

renders

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Surname</label>
```

So, you are nesting a `.col-md-2` inside a `.col-xs-3`.
If you see form-horizontal [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can try something like this for each `.form-group`

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Surname", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })    
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you now labels is looking ok but on mobile view they are not any ideas

Comment: @yoda77ni you mean like the last two (Fax No and Mobile No)?